# Android app crashes when attempting to open a specific question

Tags: bug, android-app, specific-question

Normally the app works great but always crashes when I try to open [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/97472/trick-or-treat-polyglot) question on [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-D802
- OS Version: 5.0.2 (1532219275fe2)

Comment: No repro for me. Does it crash before it's opened, or afterwards when you scroll down?

Comment: Before it opens

Comment: I have same app and same device/OS - app does not crash on the linked question. Did you try to reboot device?